# php array_filter anonymous function passing $this

Tags: php

if want to do this following:

```
    $filteredValues = array_filter($rawValues, function($rawValue) {
        return $this->validateValue($rawValue);
    });
```

`validateValue` is a private method in the same class.

How can i use $this context in array_filter in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use PHP 5.3, PHP does not recognize `$this` as closure, you need to do a trick like JavaScript:

```
$self = $this;
$filteredValues = array_filter($rawValues, function($rawValue) use ($self) {
    return $self->validateValue($rawValue);
});
```

Note that the above will only give you access to the object through the public API of the object. This is different from the 5.4 support for Closure rebinding which allows full access to `$this`.